# Magento2 - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: php, docker, magento, magento2

I installed magento2 (shop working) and I have a problem with executing the any command - I always get:

```
root@18c67198c93e:/var/www# php bin/magento cache:clear

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 64569344) (tried to allocate 5321472 bytes) in /var/www/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 202
```

When I delete the cache via the admin panel it works..

I using docker / docker-compose and I set memory_limit = 2048M (cli/php.ini, fpm/php.ini).

Console in container (app):

```
root@18c67198c93e:/var/www# php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').\"\n\";"
4096M
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  app:
    image: nginx-php:latest
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 65:80
    environment:
      - DOCKER_ROLE=app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/php/cli/php.ini:/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
      - ./docker/php/fpm/php.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - magento_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 66:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: magento
      MYSQL_DATABASE: magento
      MYSQL_USER: magento
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: magento

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    volumes:
      - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 67:9200
volumes:
  magento_data:
  elastic_data:
```

Device:

```
macOS Big Sur, M1, SSD, 16 GB RAM
```

Docker resources:
[image]

Comment: Try using php -d memory_limit=-1, which will remove the memory limit

Comment: To same problem..